# CloudKit reads notifications generated by same device

Tags: ios, notifications, cloudkit, cksubscription

When `applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)` is called, I check the unread CloudKit notifications because sometimes not all are sent to a device from CKSubscription, especially when there is a lot of low power/bad internet. I have discovered that if my device creates a record it has subscribed for changes, then lock/unlock my device (which causes `applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)` to be called) then all those notifications are read on the device. This seems unnecessary because the device caused those notifications. Is there a way to check which device created the notifications so they can be ignored or a good practice of marking them as read without going through them? I could check for notifications when it finishes creating the records and just mark as read but then there could be a notification generated at the same time by another device which I do want to read.

Comment: I have the same issue. I even asked about it on the Apple developer forums and so far I have not received any useful feedback. I may work up a "simple" test app and open an engineering case with Apple.